# Google shows "Widget tips" instead of "Widget" as title, but I don’t use this term anywhere

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

I have been working on one of the client's website from couple of months now. I have installed Yoast SEO plugin and titles was forced to put site name i.e "Widget" at the end of each post.

But from last few days I have noticed that Google results have started showing "Widget" with "Widget tips". I have never used "Widget tips" anywhere on the site as description or in the posts section.

I have set the yoast to rewrite the title with site name at the end only. I'm just wondering that how "Widget tips" is there when I have not used it any where on site. I have also tried to check the page source codes but this term has not found anywhere.

Can anyone help me to rectify the actual issue for this?

Answer (score 1):

Meta titles and descriptions are not compulsory. If Google (and other search engines) doesn't agree withe the accuracy or relevancy of the provided meta title and description it will add it's own.

Double check that your CMS isn't making this title by typing into Google 'cache:[url-address]' then click on view source.

example: cache:https://www.amazon.co.uk

Here you can see the meta title and description Google has cached, check this is the same as the one you are writing, if so then the meta data you have provided is being ignored granted the pages have been crawled since the meta data was changed.

Comment: The problem is that the OPs title tags are too short. Google is picking up the domain name as a brand and a menu element following. G can be `kind of a butt` if you do not properly manage your title tag length. We just had the exact same Q (problem) the other day.

Comment: Short titles do tend to get overwritten. I understood OP to be saying the end of the titles are not what they have set in the CMS (guessing WordPress?) so we don't know the lengths of the titles. (Unless the problem from the other day is also from OP)

Comment: I went through the various edits to find the domain name and then I did a `site:example.com` in Google. You can see that the SERP links that are like the OP is describing have short title tags and G is using the domain name then picking an element of the navigation. This is exactly what was happening with the other OP. Obviously, Google has changed something because this never happened before or is getting confused by the navigation somehow. I did not dig any further. Qhy bother? Fix the title tags and be done with it I say. ;-) Cheers Mate!!

Comment: Yes, I have been cross checked with the cache version and its exactly the same which I have written in the Meta tags. I'm agreed with closetnoc here that the short titles may be an issue for this certain problem. Let me cross check with the title lenghts and see what happens on serps.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm in agreement to if that's the case :)

Comment: @RamanKumar One thing you can do is modify the page and use Google Search Console Fetch as Google to get an example of how it will appear in the SERPs. You can modify the title and fetch the page several times until you are pleased. Then you can Submit to Index. It does not take long and you will be creating title tags of a proper length naturally without thinking about it. You will get the feel for this quickly and will not have to test pages. It only takes a day or two. ;-) Cheers!!